# AngularJS Injecting a module into parent module and using child module run and config blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to build a pretty complex app. This app involves many different state, config and run blocks in their own respective modules. I figured that one good way to tie these modules together would be to inject them into a main `app` module which holds all the injected modules. In this specific case, `subapp` is the injected, child module.

I am finding out though, that `subapp`'s run and config blocks don't run as if they were their parents, let me demonstrate that below:

HTML

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <a href="#/thestate">Head to the state!</a>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'subapp']);

angular.module('subapp', ['ui.router'])
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
            if (toState.name === "theState") {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('theState.substate', {
                    param: 1
                });
            }
        });
    })
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('theState', {
        url: '/thestate',
        template: '<div>this is the main state</div>' +
        '<a href="#/thestate/12">Go to state.substate</a>' +
        '<ui-view></ui-view>'
    })
    .state('theState.substate', {
        url: '/:param',
        template: '<div>{{id}}</div>',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
            $scope.id = $stateParams.param;
          }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Essentially, I'm trying to get Angular to run the `.run` and `.config` functions of `subapp` but use `<html ng-app="app">` in the instantiation.

Upon trying to navigate to `<a href="#/thestate">`, nothing happens. It does work, obviously, if I replace `<html ng-app="app>` with `<html ng-app="subapp">` but this wouldn't allow me to do something like, `angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'subapp', 'subapp2' ...]);`

So, my question is, why doesn't this work—(i.e., maybe `.run` is only run once, and only from the module instantiated in the html), and what is the best way to approach something modular like this?

Thanks a bunch!

EDIT**

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UCWc2cByHHjNgqAE8P7L?p=preview

Comment: Are you sure your code is not working? I would say that you make it.. it is working - check it here [#/thestate/12](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/UCWc2cByHHjNgqAE8P7L/#/thestate/12)

Comment: Actually, your plunker seems to work for me

Comment: Apologies—I have uncommented out the ```.run``` block in the main ```app``` module and everything is happily broken again ^_^. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/UCWc2cByHHjNgqAE8P7L?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IepTrb2K8JUXGS6n8YLy?p=preview)

The only issue with `.run()` of the main module is missing **`[]`**

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
  function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }])
```

The original code snippet:

```
.run('$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    })
```

is not doing what angular would expect

```
.run(['param1', 'param2', ... , function(param1, param2, ...) {}]
```

Comment: The lesson of the story: anything is possible in angularjs (and be sure to always check your syntax). :-)

Comment: Great you made it! ;) keep on playing with that diamond UI-Router ;)

Comment: Thanks Radim! :-) So it is safe to assume the number of ```.run``` blocks that can be ran is only limited to the number of modules you inject?

Comment: Sorry, was not near ;) Anyhow, all the modules which are referenced in main module (could be even via some submodule) will be correctly handled (as you expect). They will be called to run config() for all of them then run() for all of them. Other words, your expectations are all correct. Which is great ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code, run expecting function but you provide string instead

before

```
.run('$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
})
```

after

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```